# How do you say, "a very cheesy pizza"?

Tags: traduction, vocabulaire, anglais, alimentation

When I use the translator, I get "une pizza très fromagère" but when I google this French translation, I get only one result so something tells me it's wrong.

Comment: What do you mean by ' cheesy pizza'? Adjective cheesy has two meanings: adjective
1.
like cheese in taste, smell, or consistency.
2.
INFORMAL: cheap and of low quality. Which meaning do you want to convey?

Comment: There is also the meaning (informal) too emotional or romantic, in a way that is embarrassing like a cheesy love song
or a cheesy romance novel but this is out of topic here.

Comment: https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/cheesy

Comment: @Dimitris, a cheesy pizza would be one with a lot of cheese.  Using the slang/informal meaning of 'cheesy' to apply to food would only occur if someone were trying to make a tortured wordplay.

Comment: If it's not the joke about the pizza, which I can't tell because it's too cheesy.....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think *une pizza avec beaucoup de fromage* or *une pizza avec trop de fromage* communicate the meaning rather well, even though they do not have the same snappy sound as the English expression.

Answer (score 3):

If you really want a single adjective, that would be the rare :

> *Une pizza très **[fromagée](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/fromag%C3%A9)**.*

using the same suffix than:

> *sucrée*, *salée*, *épicée*, *tomatée******, *anchoiée******, *gratinée*...

Référence:

[image]

Jean Baptiste Richard de Radonvilliers
         *Enrichissement de la langue francaise; dictionnaire de mots nouveaux*
        2<sup>ème</sup> édition, 1835.

Note: This dictionary lists words French was lacking, at least at the time.
        They were only suggestions so their fate vary.

Recents usage of *fromagé(e)*:

- [L'internaute](https://www.linternaute.fr/dictionnaire/fr/definition/fromage-1/)
- [Gastronomiac](https://www.gastronomiac.com/termes_organoleptiqu/fromage/)
- [Noovomoi](https://www.noovomoi.ca/cuisiner/recettes/recette.croque-monsieur-fromage.1.9754649.html)
- [Cordial](https://www.cordial.fr/dictionnaire/definition/fromag%C3%A9.php)
- [LaSaucisseQuiADuFront](https://lasaucissequiadufront.ca/products/hamburger-fromage)
- [Vibesfood](https://vibefoods.ca/produit/delice-fromage-vegetalien/)
- [Ptitchef](https://www.ptitchef.com/recettes/plat/gratin-fromage-de-courgette-et-pomme-de-terre-fid-108816)
- [CuisineCollection](http://ja6.free.fr/fichiers/f18.htm)
- [croquantfondantgourmand](https://croquantfondantgourmand.com/gateau-fromage-aux-fraises/)

Otherwise, you would use a periphrasis:

> *Une pizza très **riche en fromage***

or

> *Une pizza très **copieuse en fromage***.

or

> *Une pizza très **généreuse en fromage***.

***** Very rare too.

Comment: Pas ouï souvent (*litotisme* néologique pour un mot réservé au tourteau pictave inconnu de mon Minus Robertus, fromagè***r***e eût mieux convenu. :-) cet adjectif dans les pizzérias… plutôt « Beurk, cette pizza est bourrée de fromage [à gerber] !!! »

Comment: @Personne Qui est donc ce petit Robert ? :-) *Formagère* me semble moins pertinent pour indiquer une intensité. Je n'utiliserais pas *salère*, *sucr[i]ère*, *épicère*, *gratinère*... et si le sens est péjoratif, *fromageuse* pourrait convenir.

Comment: ***Fromager, ère** 1*- nom et adj.: personne qui fabrique ou vend des fromages | Relatif au fromage : industrie fromagè**r**e. — ***2*** Grand arbre … — ***3*** Verbe : NÉANT !!! — fromagé est réservé au *Tourteau fromagé* du Poitou, pour le reste, tu peux changer le lien vers https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/fromager et mettre à jour le Wiki

Comment: @Personne Réponse mise à jour avec quelques références qui montrent que l'adjectif *fromagé* n'est ni récent, ni inusité, ni incompréhensible.

Answer (score 0):

What about

> une pizza très fromageuse

Comment: non, jamais entendu, jamais lu.